# Having a background color set up on a button using linear gradient

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I have a requirement to have  a button which on hover should display two colors on it. I was able to achieve mix up the colors  to a certain level but not able to produce the exact one.Below is my code,

```css
.triangle:hover{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 50%,yellow 20%);
}
```

```html
<button class='triangle'>
  Linear Check 
</button>
```

Using the above I was able to produce a image like this one on below
[image]

Please let me know if this is possible and  can be achieved using linear gradient .
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question here? cuz I feel you already answered it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with 2 conic gradients.

```css
.triangle{
  padding:20px;
  border:none;
  --g:red 135deg,yellow 0; /* the coloration */
  --p:30%;/* the position */
  background:
    conic-gradient(from -180deg at 50% var(--p)             ,var(--g)) top,
    conic-gradient(from -135deg at 50% calc(100% - var(--p)),var(--g)) bottom;
  background-size:100% 51%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button class='triangle'>
 some content
</button>

<button class='triangle' style="--p:60%">
 some content
</button>


<button class='triangle' style="--p:20%;--g:blue 135deg,pink 0">
 some content
</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the edges curved (red color gradient) rather than have sharp edges?

Comment: @Developer like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sh0x5zvL/ ?

Comment: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvAw7.jpg".This is the gradient shape I am trying to achieve.Thanks

Comment: if you could pls help me with this. Been stuck with this for a while .Also can this be achieved using the gradients.

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use `rgba()` or `hsl` or HEX:

```
background: linear-gradient(deg or (from to),rgba(),rgba());
```

Comment: I tried actually using linear gradient initially but was not able to change the border of the gradient color.In my case the red color  gradient needs to have a curved edge similar to the image but need curved edges rather than sharped one

Comment: @developer if this is a new question, ask a new question ;)

Comment: just set the border property to unset;
.triangle:hover{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 50%,yellow 20%);
  border:unset;
}